# on click working from console but not in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I have a on click jquery function written inside ready() function but still it does not work on the site. It does work when I paste the code in the console.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(".product-video-popup").click(function(){
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 1250 }, 2000);

}); 
});
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue described, we might get a proper chance to see what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery(document).on("click",".product-video-popup",function(){
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 1250 }, 2000);

}); 
});
```

Let me know if it works or not. Its might be a case when you are updating the DOM dynamically. Please check.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I tried this. even this works just from console and not by adding in the code.

Comment: It worked. I was trying to click before the page completely loads.

Comment: Great glad it helped. :) @FahadUddin

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
       jQuery("div").animate({ scrollTop: 1250 }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:150px;overflow:auto">
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div><br>

<button>Return the vertical position of the scrollbar</button>
<p>Move the scrollbar down and click the button again.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is working fine.
I think your are doing a mistake is create a DOM element or not include a jquery library.

I mentioned the working is below.
[Js fiddle link for scroll down](https://jsfiddle.net/wordpressviews/nze69fug/)

Comment: Thanks. the problem was that I was clicking before the page loaded completely.